# Instance initializer causes 'dummy' application to stop working

Tags: ember-cli

I am learning ember-cli and started with the [tutorial/guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/orientation/). Everything went fine till I added my own instance initializer and the application stopped working. After playing around a bit with various options, I find that just doing a `touch instance-initializer/foo.js` also causes the same issue. What started me on this path was trying to pull AWS amplify as a service and configuring it, but removed all the code and found that just creating a zero length file in the instance initializer directory causes the same issue.

Obviously I don't have a clear understanding of how ember-cli uses instance initializers. Any help here is appreciated.

ember-cli: 3.15.1
node: 13.6.0
os: linux x64

Comment: An empty file is probably causing a failure when ember attempts to run an initialize function in the file. Going back to your original issue ca you post the original initializer you are attempting to build and we can help with that?

Comment: sorry for the very late reply @jrjohnson. I found a starting project in Vue which got me over the initial hump and I decided to use that instead. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.